# How do I get day number from a date in abap?

Tags: abap

I need to convert a date in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format to a number that say which day in the year it is. I.E '01/01/YYYY'=1 and '12/31/YYYY'=365. Is there any built in function to do this in ABAP? I've tried googling but I couldn't find any functions which did this

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely unnecessary to rely on any function module that may or may not be present in your system. Just use basic built-in language elements:

```
DATA: l_my_date TYPE d, " note that the data type D is YYYYMMDD 
      l_jan_01  TYPE d, " This will be jan 1 of the needed year
      l_day     TYPE i.

l_my_date = ...whatever... 
l_jan_01 = l_my_date. 
l_jan_01+4 = '0101'. " or any other means to get the first day of the year. 
l_day = l_my_date - l_jan_01 + 1.
```

Comment: I probably would have set `l_jan_01` to `'19700101'` in the data declaration section. And then move `l_my_date(4)` to `l_jan_01(4)`.

Comment: @vwegert Hi, I admire your answers and comments, in fact, I think your answers is more efficient, however, if the function exists in SAP why should I create my own?

Comment: @nmiranda Because you're probably using an undocumented unreleased internal function that might disappear anytime without notice. I prefer using the supported built-in language statements...

Answer (score 3):

Here you go in one line of code:

```
DATA(g_day) = p_date - CONV d( p_date(4) && '0101' ) + 1.
```

Comment: Excellent - I'm still not yet used to using the new expressions all of the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function module: `HR_AUPBS_MONTH_DAY`.

You have to pass an initial date and an end date, and it will return the number of days in between (this is what you want):

```
CALL FUNCTION 'HR_AUPBS_MONTH_DAY'
  EXPORTING BEG_DA     = P_BEGDA    " Here you should put the first day of the year
            END_DA     = P_ENDDA    " Here you put the date
  IMPORTING NO_CAL_DAY = P_CAL_DAY. " This is what you want
```